# rest api post method not working for basic auth in meanjs 0.5.0

Tags: meanjs

I tried to check post method of meanjs (0.5.0) in postman with basic auth but it doesn't seem to be working. I am giving the correct credentials.

It show below error:

`{
    "message": "User is not authorized"
}`

Any idea what can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in `./node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js` that `_usernameField` name is `usernameOrEmail` instead of `username`.

So I passed below json object with content header as "application/json" from postman and it got connected successfully:

```
{
   "usernameOrEmail":"test",
   "password":"test"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should check the policies file defined for that module in `/module/your-module/server/policies/` and see if the roles/permissions are ok.

Then check if the credentials you're using belong to a user that has the correct roles.

Comment: Thanks but I already checked all that. Role is 'user' and allows are for resource '/api/forums' and permission is permissions: ['get', 'post']. I am also using the correct credentials. I have observed that no POST request is working in postman for this demo meanjs site.

Comment: I found in *./node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js* that _usernameField name is "usernameOrEmail" instead of "username". So I passed `{"usernameOrEmail":"test", "password":"test"}` with content header as "application/json", it got connected.

Comment: Happy you got it working. You should answer your own question explaining what you did for future readers.